# What is this horror movie with a disfigured blond woman who seduces then kills men?

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

I saw this movie probably 15 years ago. It was about a blond woman with a disfigured face (the face is never shown), who seduces men and then brutally kills their families/friends and etc. When a man sees/learns about that and tries to stop/kill her, someone else saves her and the circle goes on and on.

Comment: Is there a sci-fi or fantasy element to this movie? From the description here, it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Nope, no sci-fi or fantasy, It was just a horror story.

Comment: In that case, the question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 11):

Is it possible it was an episode from the **television** series [*Masters of Horror*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448190/?ref_=tt_ov_inf) named [*Jenifer*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0643108/?ref_=tt_urv)?

It's not quite as old but in the same ballpark and the format is different. However, she is disfigured and blonde plus the episode begins and ends with something similar to what you wrote:

> who seduces men and then brutally kills their families/friends and
>   etc. When a man sees/learns about that and tries to stop/kill her,
>   someone else saves her and the circle goes on and on

Comment: Yes! This is it. Omg, thanks a lot! I tried to find it for quite some time now, and yea i forgot when i saw it. Cheers and thanks again!

Comment: Of course. Done, i dont have 15 reps yet though.

Comment: No biggie. Glad it was able to be ID'd.

Comment: And this is certainly fantasy.

Comment: @Voael: And can you click on the checkmark by the voting buttons? :) That's how you actually accept it.

Comment: "Of course. Done, i dont have 15 reps yet though."  You don't need to have 15 rep to accept -- the points for that aren't taken from the questioner.